# Should self generated transaction ids be exchanged in HTTP synchronous requests

Tags: http, soap, transactions, client-server, synchronous

I am new to the HTTP world. My sincere apologies if the question is too trivial.

I created a HTTP client which send a SOAP message to a 3rd party server. My client sends a synchronous request and has a timeout value of 15 seconds. The API is used to update user balance, so it is very critical. I send the userId in the SOAP request and amount to be added/deducted from user balance to the server. The server responds with Status of 0=SUCCESS or 1=FAILURE

Now considering that multiple failures can occur at server and I might hit the server multiple times for the same user in a day, should there be a transaction id added in the message part. If yes, what would be the use cases for it. As per my understanding, client would always know which transaction it initiated, so it can do the transaction bookkeeping on its own. I would also need to reconcile the transactions with the server on daily basis (which could happen using userId).

Note: Server APIs are being developed and can change right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use HTTPS not HTTP for anything sensitive.

Next, it sounds like your Client is persistent (i.e. not a browser).  In this case it would be useful to return a Transaction ID from the Server which the Client can store, and as you say this facilitates daily audits. This is probably useful because for the Audit request the Server can return a set of Transaction IDs which you can check, in addition to other data.

Answer (score 0):

TCP will provide the underlying reliable connection so you are correct that each Client SOAP request does not need an additional mechanism to track its response from the server.   But, with that said, an additional message level GUID is helpful for troubleshooting purposes.  It will allow you later to track and trace  the exact client message to the server if you experience issues.